# C++ extern storage class life-span

Tags: c++, extern, storage-class-specifier

I am a C++ newbie and come from a Java background. 
I would like to confirm the following:

I am reading **C++ by dissection by Ira Pohl** and the book states that the 
life-span for a file/`extern` variable/function is the duration of the program *(which makes sense because the variable is not declared in a class)*.

What I want to know; is that also the case for a variable declared in a class? If not, if a variable is declared in a class does that make the variable use the `auto` storage class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A member variable in a class has a life-span corresponding to the life-span of the class's instances, unless declared `static`.

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
    static int y;
};
```

This `Foo`, and therefore its `x`, has program life-span:

```
static Foo foo;
```

This one is `auto`:

```
int main() { Foo foo; }
```

This one is dynamically allocated and lives until the `Foo` is `delete`'d:

```
int main() { Foo *foo = new Foo; }
```

In each case, the `y` has program life-span.